# LVALUE required as left operand of assignment in c program

Tags: c++, c

What's the difference between

`c=a%2;`

and

`a%2=c`;

I am getting this error for the second one:

> lvalue required as left operand of the assignment

Comment: What do you expect as the result of the second one?

Comment: it would assign the remainder value(when a id divided by 2) to c.                   still a learner

Comment: The left thing is the one being assigned, not the right one.

Comment: So you believe an assignment can somehow magically change the direction, sometimes assigning right-hand side to the left, and other times assigning left-hand side to the right? What do you believe `a=b;` does - which value is assigned to which variable?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: in Prolog it can. Albeit the questioner is very much a beginner, the logic expected in the question is consistent so far. In fact, it can even be provided via custom types, just we, C++ crew are not used to that logic. (And yes, I still think that `operator=()` should have been `operator:=()` or sg. similar, non-commutative math op.)

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. Remove the tag of the unrelated language!

Comment: Please choose a language. C and C++ are different languages, and they have different concepts of "values".

Comment: @lorro From what little I remember of Prolog, I don't believe it has a concept of assignment in the first place. And rules in Prolog are very clearly directional, with left-hand side and right-hand side playing distinct roles. I don't recall anything there that would exhibit a symmetry and provoke this kind of confusion. Having said that, Prolog for me is a distant memory from decades ago, I may very well be missing something obvious.

Comment: `a%2=c`: `a%2` will return a constant value that is why you cannot assign to it a value

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assignment in C and C++ is always of the form

`assigned = to_assign;`

The languages don't attempt to duplicate what you could do as a mathematician working with a load of algebra.

So `c = a % 2` is allowed, but `a % 2 = c` isn't. The latter would attempt to assign `c` to `a % 2`.

*Very informally speaking*, you can't have `a % 2` on the left hand side of an assignment since you can't take the address of it. Still speaking rather informally, you can think of assignment as `lvalue = rvalue` where `lvalue` means "left value" and `rvalue` means "right value". That explains the error message reported by your compiler.

Comment: got it. thanks for helping

Comment: Suggestion: 'is always in the form ... for _base_types_'. While it's a convention that's preferred to be kept, it can be overridden in e.g. DSLs. Without those, we wouldn't have `boost::spirit<>`.

Comment: @lorro: I have strong doubts this wouks in C!

Comment: @Olaf: maybe not in c, surely does in c++.